# I need to create a key in lua consisting of 2 IDS which I can put a check on to occur together only once. What datastructure I should use and how?

Tags: function, lua, key

I've recently started working in lua. I'm trying to create function in which I needd to create a composite key consisting of 2 elements which should occur only once together. They can occur multiple times but with different combinations. One combination should be unique. Suggest me what data structure I should go for and how?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to go with a table where your key is the actual position in the table.

as in:

```
    my_super_duper_key = key1..key2
    my_super_duper_key2 = key2..key1
    if table[my_super_duper_key] == nil and table[my_super_duper_key2] == nil then
       table[my_super_duper_key] = true
       table[my_super_duper_key2] = true
    end
```

If your keys are always in the same order or if it's a different key depending which is first you can throw the _key2 out of it... :)